# Which people in the Bible are antichrists?

Tags: lds, cain, antichrist

Mormons have the view that [antichrist](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/antichrist) refers to anyone who lives to deny/replace Christ. Korihor, Sherem, and Nehor are examples from the Book of Mormon; are there specific people from the Bible?

I got this question after reading this related question, where the idea that [antichrist refers to "The Antichrist" (specifically one of the beasts in Revelation) is debated](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25065/why-is-the-second-beast-of-revelation-called-the-antichrist/25079#25079). Looks like the Bible (1st John 2:22) says antichrist just means someone who denies Christ. I like to be able to recognize antichist teachings, and I'm grateful the Book of Mormon points out prevalent ones in our day. I think the bible and book of mormon support each other, so again my question is specifically who has been an antichrist in the Bible? any specific examples? Specifically an answer from either Mormon doctrine or just what the Bible says.

I'm thinking Cain, and his idea that he didn't have to be his brother's keeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word antichrist is not, to my knowledge, explicitly attributed to specific persons. But it is attributed to groups of people that taught false doctrines:

1 John 2:18

> 18 Little children, it is the last time: and as ye have heard that antichrist shall come, even now are there many antichrists; whereby we know that it is the last time.

2 John 1:7

> 7 For many deceivers are entered into the world who confess not that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh. This is a deceiver and an antichrist.

1 John 2:22

> 22 Who is a liar but he that denieth that Jesus is the Christ? 
>   He is antichrist, that denieth the Father and the Son.

1 John 4:3

> 3 And every spirit that confesseth not that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is not of God: and this is that spirit of antichrist, whereof ye have heard that it should come; and even now already is it in the world.

I am no expert on early christian heresies, but from the epistles alone, you find there were people professing christianity who:

- denied the resurrection (1 Corinthians) - especially the bodily resurrection
- denied him coming in the flesh (1 John) - I think this means they believed he was just spirit, but again, I'm no expert, and these things are not always clearly stated in the epistles
- taught that the law is the way to salvation, including circumcision

and all kinds of other stuff. You can see how these qualify as "antichrist". Maybe someone more into this stuff can help out here.

Comment: Thanks brother. This answers part of what I was wondering: what antichrist doctrines have people taught in the Bible. And yeah, Mormons believe that Christ came in the flesh, both with mortal flesh and resurrected with an immortal body of flesh and bone.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only antichrist specifically identified from the bible is **Lucifer**, the great antichrist, as is mentioned in the link you've provided.

You're right about **Cain** though, it is mentioned in the scriptures (Pearl of Great Price) that he loved Satan more than God (see [Moses 5:13,18](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/5.13,18?lang=eng#12)). This by definition makes him an antichrist.

The [link](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/antichrist) you provided lists all of the references in the standard works to all the other individuals who were specifically identified as antichrists.

I imagine there could be more that fit the definition, but to my knowledge no one has yet put the work into identifying them all. I will speculate however that it could be debated that one other person who could be considered an antichrist is **Judas Iscariot** (see [Luke 22:3](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/luke/22.3?lang=eng#2)). Judas is often regarded as a [son of perdition](http://eom.byu.edu/index.php/Sons_of_Perdition), so I don't think it's much of a stretch to suggest he was also an antichrist.

Answer (score 0):

In all the bible translations that I have checked, these are the only verses which use the word *antichrist*:

> Little children, it is the last time: and as ye have heard that antichrist shall come, even now are there many antichrists; whereby we know that it is the last time. ([1 John 2:18](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-jn/2.18?lang=eng#17))
>
> Who is a liar but he that denieth that Jesus is the Christ? He is antichrist, that denieth the Father and the Son. ([1 John 2:22](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-jn/2.22?lang=eng#21))
>
> And every spirit that confesseth not that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is not of God: and this is that spirit of antichrist, whereof ye have heard that it should come; and even now already is it in the world. ([1 John 4:3](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-jn/4.3?lang=eng#2))
>
> For many deceivers are entered into the world, who confess not that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh. This is a deceiver and an antichrist. ([2 John 7](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/2-jn/1.7?lang=eng#6))

None of these scriptures identifies the antichrist or the antichrists to be any particular person. The LDS Bible Dictionary makes some interesting statements though in the [entry Antichrist](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bd/antichrist?lang=eng&letter=a):

> A word used by John to describe one who would assume the guise of Christ but in reality would be opposed to Christ (1 Jn. 2:18–22; 4:3–6; 2 Jn. 1:7). In a broader sense it is anyone or anything that counterfeits the true gospel or plan of salvation and that openly or secretly is set up in opposition to Christ. The great antichrist is Lucifer, but he has many assistants both as spirit beings and as mortals. See 2 Thes. 2:1–12; Rev. 13:17; Jacob 7:1–23; Alma 1:2–16; 30:6–60.

So in a broad sense, there are lots of antichrists. There are some similarities between the antichrists in the Book of Mormon and Judas Iscariot, as well as Hananias and his wife Saphira who lie to the Holy Ghost and lose their lives (see [Acts 5:1-10](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/acts/5.1-10?lang=eng)). The similarity consists in the way they end up dying (for Judas' death see [Acts 1:16-19](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/acts/1.16-19?lang=eng#15)).